# MATLAB For Loop to count #s in one column based off of entries in another

Tags: matlab, for-loop, multiple-columns

I have 50 spreadsheets with multiple scored columns:
One column (AG) has numbers coded 1:13, the other, (SEC) has numbers coded 1:6.

Ex:

```
AG   SEC
 1    1
 2    1
 4    1
 13   1
 3    2
 12   2
```

I want to write a for loop that counts all the 1s in .SEC that correspond to #s 1:5 in .AG. (output would be 3 - it wouldn't count the 1 corresponding to 13). I need this to happen for all #s in .SEC (1:6). The final output would have the spreadsheet name in the first column, and counts for .SEC=1,2,3,4,5,6 in each of the proceeding columns.

My current code creates a variable for total .AG counts in .SEC, but is nondiscriminatory (counts the amount of times any number is given in .AG instead of counting for specific values)

`scoringfiles` is a 50-item path list (when I do `readtable(scoringfiles)` it iterates through the list and reads through excel files. `filelist` is a 50-item list with just filenames.

```
for i=1:length(scoringfiles)

  if contains(filelist(i,:),"sheet")
        disp(i)
        sheetnum=[sheetnum extractBetween(filelist{i},1,4)]
        
        s1=[s1 length(find(readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).SEC==1))]
        s2=[s2 length(find(readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).SEC==2))]    
        s3=[s3 length(find(readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).SEC==3))]
        s4=[s4 length(find(readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).SEC==4))]
        s5=[s5 length(find(readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).SEC==5))]
        s6=[s6 length(find(readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).SEC==6))]

  elseif contains(filelist(i,:),"graph")
       disp("not sheet")

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, `i` and `j` are the imaginary unit. To avoid redefining it, you should make a habit of using `ii` and `jj` as your loop variable instead of `i` and `j`.

Now back to the main question:

Let's assume you've read the file contents into the `data` variable. This is going to be a `Nx2` array.

You only care about AG when it is in the range `1:5`. Let's create a `filter` array with `true` where AG is in the range and `false` elsewhere.

```matlab
filter = data(:, 1) >= 1 & data(:, 1) <= 5;
```

Let's first split the columns into two variables for legibility. Use the filter to select just the rows that match our criteria.

```matlab
ag = data(filter, 1);
sec = data(filter, 2);
```

Now you want to go through each *unique* value in `sec`, and count the number of `ag` entries.

```matlab
unique_sec = unique(sec);
counts = zeros(size(unique_sec)); % Preallocate a zeros array to save our answer in
for ii = 1:length(unique_sec)
    sec_value = unique_sec(ii); % Get the value of SEC
    matches = sec == sec_value; % Make a filter for rows that have this value
    % matches is a logical array. true = 1, false = 0. sum gives number of trues.
    counts(ii) = sum(matches); 
end
```

Alternatively, you could perform the filter for `1 <= AG <= 5` inside the loop if you don't want to filter before:

```matlab
ag = data(:, 1);
sec = data(:, 2);
unique_sec = unique(sec);
counts = zeros(size(unique_sec)); 
for ii = 1:length(unique_sec)
    sec_value = unique_sec(ii);
    matches = sec == sec_value & ag >= 1 & ag <= 5; % Add more conditions to the filter
    counts(ii) = sum(matches); 
end
```

If you want to do this for multiple files, iterate over them and read the files into the `data` variable.

Comment: Hi, I am new to questions on stack overflow and I did not mention that the variable, scoring files, is a list of 50 paths that I iterate through and use readtable to look at the columns SEC and AG. Setting the columns as variables does not work because the columns are only referred to once I am using the readtable command. Does this make sense? I think using the filter would be immensely helpful, but if you have time, I'd love a follow up based off of this clarification :) (P.s. I have added this to the original post)

Comment: Hi Pranav, thank you so much for your help! I had never considered using a filter. I was able to add the filter directly into the for loop, creating tables for each # in .SEC based off of a filter in .AG. My final solution just adds the filter to the original code posted and works perfectly. I have posted it to this entry! I wouldn't have figured it out without your help (and I have been trying to do this for too too long). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to apply a filter thanks to the help of Pranav. It is as simple as adding the filter to each line of the for loop as it iterates through reading my spreadsheets. See below:

THIS EXAMPLE ONLY LOOKS AT S1 and S2. Realistically, I have this for 6 different #s creating 6 tables with counts per spreadsheet.

```
for i=1:length(scoringfiles)
    filter1 = readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).AG >= 1;
    filter2 = readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).AG <= 5;
  if contains(filelist(i,:),"sheet")
        disp(i)
        sheetnum=[sheetnum extractBetween(filelist{i},1,4)]
        
        s1=[s1 length(find(readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).SEC==1 & filter1 & filter2))]
        s2=[s2 length(find(readtable(scoringfiles(i,:)).SEC==2 & filter1 & filter2))]    
       

  elseif contains(filelist(i,:),"graph")
       disp("not sheet")

  end
end
```